# Why do we consider the zeroes of the expression when solving rational inequalities?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

When finding the solution set of rational inequalities (of the form $ {x-3\over x+2} \geq 0 $ etc.) , why do we consider the "zeroes" of the expression.

So I've been taught to solve this as follows:

First,
$x-3 = 0  \implies x = 3 \quad and \quad x+2\not= 0 \implies x\not=-2 \,\text{(b/c, undefined)} $ are "points of interest".

Sketch a number line from $-∞$ to $+∞$, with the points of interest ($-2$ & $3$) labeled.
Then we check each region bound by those numbers to see if they're positive/negative and label them as such.

[image: Solution set]

The thing I'm confused by is why do we check those zeroes? What tells us that the signs don't suddenly flip at some other random value? Can someone explain in detail this working, suggest a better method or point me to other resources which "prove" the things I'm talking about.

Comment: It may be easier to instead use$$\frac{x-3}{x+2}\ge0\iff(x-3)(x+2)\ge0\quad(x\ne-2)$$then apply methods for solving quadratic inequalities.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you explain how those are identical? [I'm but a lowly highschool junior]

Comment: Because $\cfrac{1}{x+2}$ and $(x+2)$ have the same sign

Comment: The inequality is multiplied with $(x+2)^2$ , which is positive for $x\ne -2$, hence the solution set does not change , if we consider that $-2$ must be ruled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, consider $$\frac{x-a}{x-b} \ge 0, \ a\gt b$$ For a fraction to be non-negative, we need the numerator and the denominator to have the same parity, or that the numerator be zero.

If both are positive, then $$x-a\ge 0 \implies x\ge a$$and $$x-b \gt 0 \implies x\gt b \hspace{1 cm} \because x-b\ne 0$$ Taking the inetrsection of the two requirements, we get $$x\ge a \hspace{2 cm} (\mathbf 1)$$

If both are negative, then $$x-a \lt 0 \implies x\lt a \\ x-b \lt 0 \implies x\lt b $$ This means $$x\lt b \hspace{2 cm} (\mathbf 2)$$ Now, either of the two cases can happen, so we take the union of $(\mathbf 1)$ and $(\mathbf 2)$: $$x\in(-\infty, b) \cup [a, \infty) $$ To answer your question more directly, we consider the zeroes of each factor, because that’s precisely where the factor changes its sign.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, so how can one extend this to more 'complicated' forms where there are repaeted factors or fractional powers involve. I really want to just learn how to solve all kinds of inequalities and so if you could point me to some learning resources. Like I'm curious if I can get an imaginary solution set from an inequality and sstuff like that.

Comment: @Shaheer ziya I don’t believe I know of any such resources, sorry. For more factors, the method is similar, although many textbooks generalize this to the method you described in your post. I’m not sure about fractional powers.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Foreman stated in his comment (and taking into note my own comment), the inequalities
$$\frac{x-3}{x+2}\ge0$$ and $$(x-3)(x+2)\ge 0$$
are equivalent. It's vividly seen in the graph below:

[image]

The graph shows that $$\operatorname{sgn}\left(\frac{x-3}{x+2}\right)=\operatorname{sgn}\left((x-3)(x+2)\right), \ \ x \neq -2$$

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot! By the way, where can I learn more about the nuances of these inequalities and stuff. Do you know any good resources where I can learn more about inequalities?

Comment: @Shaheerziya If you mean this kind of basic inequalities by "inequalities and stuff", then any (as far as I know) school textbooks are useful.

Comment: I own quite a lot of high school textbooks but they are very restricting. Our course ( A-level Maths) only requires being able to solve up to quadratic inequalities and nothing else. I have little idea about solving complicated inequalities with square roots and repeated factors and stuff with fractions and I'm also very interested in the proofs aspect of this. If you know anything I'd appreciate it, but it's fine otherwise!